# Python aplicado a un juego de señales. Generar emparejamientos y asignar valores

Tags: python, python-2.7

Imaginemos un juego en el que individuos por parejas juegan a enseñarse señales durante 3 rondas.
Asignamos las señales iniciales que produce cada participante aleatoriamente:

```
Sen1_part1= random.choice("ABCD")
Sen1_part2= random.choice("ABCD")
Sen1_part3= random.choice("ABCD")
Sen1_part4= random.choice("ABCD")
```

Ahora, creamos un diccionario para cada participante donde deseamos guardar las señales que produce su pareja en la primera ronda. Es decir, si el participante 2 tiene asignada la señal A, en el experimento esto significa que ha enseñado la señal A a su pareja. Si participante 1 ha jugado con participante 2, deseamos guardar en Mem_part1 un 1 como valor en la señal A del diccionario. Así con los cuatro participantes (deseamos siempre guardar en el diccionario la señal asignada a la pareja).

```
Mem_part1 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0} 
Mem_part2 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0} 
Mem_part3 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0} 
Mem_part4 = {"A":0,"B":0,"C":0,"D":0}
```

Necesitamos por lo tanto definir de alguna manera los emparejamientos a lo largo de las cuatro rondas. Se me había ocurrido que por medio de una lista (o con un array en numpy). Algo así:

```
orden_emparejamientos = ([[1,2,3,4]  #1 juega con 2, 3 juega con 4
                          [1,3,2,4]  #1 con 3, 2 con 4
                          [1,4,2,3]  #1 con 4, 2 con 3
```

Sin embargo, no sé cómo podría ser útil una lista o un array para definir los emparejamientos en el juego.

En definitiva, deseamos que el programa establezca un orden de emparejamientos y vaya guardando en el diccionario de memoria las señales que ve cada participante (estrictamente, las asignadas aleatoriamente a su pareja).

Comment: No entiendo muy bien a que quieres llegar con tu pregunta, incluso, según entiendo, no tienes necesidad de un orden, pero no entiendo tu parte de almacenar (+1) los valores... puedes explicarte mejor?

Comment: Se trata de aprender Python diseñando un pequeño experimento-juego. La matriz da un orden de juego para cada ronda. El orden determinaría qué participantes juegan entre sí. En el ejemplo juegan 1-2 y 3-4 (porque están juntos). Me gustaría, en definitiva, almacenar en la memoria (diccionario) de cada participante, la señal que ha producido su pareja (y la pareja viene determinada por un orden que podríamos cambiar en una matriz). Con +1 me refería a que almacenamos con valor 1 la selección de la pareja(i.e., si 1 juega con 2, almacenamos en Mem_part1 la señal que se asignó aleatoriamente a 2.

Comment: No entiendo la pregunta. Los diccionarios en Python no tienen orden. Creo que tienes que editar tu pregunta para agregar información que ayude a comprender lo que quieres. Sigue esta guía [mcve].

Comment: He reeditado la pregunta para marcar la diferencia con una consulta anterior que hice y que quedó resuelta.

Comment: Lo más sencillo es partir la lista en parejas y usar if-else para saber que señal coger y en que diccionario guardarla en funcion de los numeros de cada pareja. Esto es una locura si se aplica a cada par y cada ronda (código muy largo y redundante) si no se usan funciones, de hecho yo usaría POO directamente creando objetos para cada jugador.  Deberias aportar lo que has intentado hacer o al menos si puedes usar funciones o POO.

Comment: No entiendo por qué la pregunta permanece marcada como duplicada. Queda explicado de manera manifiesta que lo que se pretende es diferente a otra pregunta anterior, por lo que no me parece de utilidad alguna que la pregunta quede anulada. No es una manera óptima ni eficaz de ayudar a principiantes desde luego, sino más bien censurar la posibilidad de que transitemos de menos a más conocimiento de programación. Gracias sin embargo a FJSevilla

Comment: @toledano claramente, el OP busca cómo agrupar los turnos. Un diccionario no es la solución, pero quizás otra estructura como una lista de tuplas lo puede ser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dado que ya te has autocontestado voy a aportar un ejemplo sencillo de como podriamos hacerlo con programción orientada a objetos (es solo una posibilidad, en programación como en la vida hay muchos caminos, lo difícil es saber elegir el correcto... XD).

En este caso la clase `Partida` solo necesita al instanciarla pasarle a su constructor la lista de señales posibles y la lista de emparejamientos.

La lista de señales (puede ser también una cadena o cualquier otro iterable) contiene las señales que puede elegir cada jugador, puede tener el número que queramos de elementos.

La lista de emparejamientos contiene los nombres de los jugadores organizados por rondas igual que hace tú. Los nombres se toman de la primera ronda para construir un diccionario donde se almacena el nombre de cada jugador como clave y como valor el objeto que le pertenece de la clase `Jugador`.

La clase `Jugador` almacena las memorias y genera las señales de cada jugador.

```
import random

class Partida():
    def __init__(self, emparejamientos, senales):
        self.emparejamientos = emparejamientos
        #Diccionario que guarda el nombre de cada jugador asociado a su objeto de la clase Jugador()
        self.jugadores = {nombre: Partida.Jugador(senales)
                            for nombre in emparejamientos[0]}

    def jugar(self):
        salida =('\n    Pareja: {0} vs {1}:' +
                 '\n      {0} muestra la señal {2} a {1}' +
                 '\n      {1} muestra la señal {3} a {0}')

        for n, ronda in enumerate(self.emparejamientos):
            parejas = [ronda[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(ronda), 2)]
            print('\nJugando ronda {0}:'.format(n+1), end="")
            for jugador1, jugador2 in parejas:
                sen1 = self.jugadores[jugador1].generar_senal()
                sen2 = self.jugadores[jugador2].generar_senal()
                self.jugadores[jugador1].guardar_observada(sen2)
                self.jugadores[jugador2].guardar_observada(sen1)
                print(salida.format(jugador1, jugador2, sen1, sen2))

    def imprimir_memorias(self):
        salida = (  'Memorias del jugador {0}:' +
                    '\n    Señales mostradas: {1}' +
                    '\n    Señales observadas: {2}')

        for jugador in self.jugadores:
            print(salida.format(jugador, *self.jugadores[jugador].obtener_memorias()))


    class Jugador():
        def __init__(self, senales):
            self.senales = senales
            self.mem_mostradas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}
            self.men_observadas = {senal: 0 for senal in senales}

        def generar_senal(self):
            sen = random.choice(self.senales)
            self.mem_mostradas[sen] += 1
            return(sen)

        def guardar_observada(self, sen):
            self.men_observadas[sen] += 1

        def obtener_memorias(self):
            return(self.mem_mostradas, self.men_observadas)





#  Ahora solo queda instanciar nuestra clase Partida y le pasamos los
## jugadores y las señales posibles para que simule un juego:

emparejamientos =  [['Juán', 'Pedro', 'Raquel', 'María'],
                    ['Raquel', 'Pedro', 'Juán', 'María']]
señales = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

juego = Partida(emparejamientos, señales)
juego.jugar()
print()
juego.imprimir_memorias()
```

La salida obtenida en este caso es:

```
Jugando ronda 1:
    Pareja: Juán vs Pedro:
      Juán muestra la señal C a Pedro
      Pedro muestra la señal C a Juán

    Pareja: Raquel vs María:
      Raquel muestra la señal D a María
      María muestra la señal A a Raquel

Jugando ronda 2:
    Pareja: Raquel vs Pedro:
      Raquel muestra la señal C a Pedro
      Pedro muestra la señal D a Raquel

    Pareja: Juán vs María:
      Juán muestra la señal B a María
      María muestra la señal B a Juán

Memorias del jugador Raquel:
    Señales mostradas: {'D': 1, 'B': 0, 'E': 0, 'C': 1, 'A': 0}
    Señales observadas: {'D': 1, 'B': 0, 'E': 0, 'C': 0, 'A': 1}
Memorias del jugador María:
    Señales mostradas: {'D': 0, 'B': 1, 'E': 0, 'C': 0, 'A': 1}
    Señales observadas: {'D': 1, 'B': 1, 'E': 0, 'C': 0, 'A': 0}
Memorias del jugador Juán:
    Señales mostradas: {'D': 0, 'B': 1, 'E': 0, 'C': 1, 'A': 0}
    Señales observadas: {'D': 0, 'B': 1, 'E': 0, 'C': 1, 'A': 0}
Memorias del jugador Pedro:
    Señales mostradas: {'D': 1, 'B': 0, 'E': 0, 'C': 1, 'A': 0}
    Señales observadas: {'D': 0, 'B': 0, 'E': 0, 'C': 2, 'A': 0}
```

De esta forma podemos crear un juego en el que participen los jugadores que queramos, que tenga las rondas que queramos y las señaels que queramos. Es solo un ejemplo muy básico pero podemos hacer que los jugadores sean personas reales que introduzcan las señales desde la terminal, incluso jugando cada uno en un ordenador si queremos, pero la idea es la misma.

Tu código es realmente más sencillo pero no es adaptable, es decir, si cambiamos el nombre de los jugadores, su número, el número de rondas, la cantidad de señales, etc hay que modificar el código para que funcione. La gracia de las clases es que funcionan como un molde, un patrón. En este caso solo hay que instanciar la clase con los parámetros adecuados, pero el código es el mismo si tenemos 4 jugadores o 40, 4 rondas o 100, etc.

Es decir, si queremos añadir dos jugadores más (Pepe y Laura), una señal más (`F`) y una ronda más solo instanciamos adecuadamente la clase, pero el código es el mismo:

```
emparejamientos =  [['Raquel', 'Laura', 'Pedro', 'Juán', 'Pepe', 'María'],
                    ['Laura', 'Pedro', 'Raquel', 'Pepe', 'Juán', 'María'],
                    ['Raquel', 'Pepe', 'Pedro', 'Juán', 'Laura', 'María']]
señales = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']

juego = Partida(emparejamientos, señales)
juego.jugar()
juego.imprimir_memorias()
```

Comment: Extraordinaria respuesta @FJSevilla Voy a tardar un poco en asimilar todo lo que me has explicado. Mañana estudiaré a fondo esto para ver si lo comprendo paso a paso. Por otra parte, parece ser que necesito conseguir algún punto de "reputación" más para votar adecuadamente como se merece esta respuesta, que es sensacional. Lo haré sin duda en cuanto esté habilitado. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @pyring No te agobies por la POO, lo natural es empezar por la programación estructurada y ir introduciendote poco a poco en los conceptos de la POO. Lo bueno de lenguajes como Python (o C++) es que al ser multiparadigma te permiten hacer este camino en el mismo lenguaje. Python es para mi, junto a C++, uno de los mejores lenguajes para aprender (y por supuesto para desarrollar luego) asi que pasito a pasito. Yo ando ahora peleandome con [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) pasito a pasito también... Ánimo. :)

Comment: Estoy justo ahora empezando a explorar el código que amablemente has elaborado y compartido. Estoy a la vez leyendo el tutorial básico que en el sitio web oficial de Python trata el tema de "clases". Me va a llevar un tiempo familiarizarme con todo (no es mi campo) pero me parece sumamente interesante para aplicar en experimentos sobre lingüística. Lo interesante de esto, para mí, es comprenderlo para aplicarlo al estudio dinámicas evolutivas. Estas navidades, me las pasaré estudiando esto :) Por cierto, ¿no se pueden enviar mensajes privados a usuarios con intereses comunes? Sl2

Comment: La verdad es que es un lenguaje que se aprende pronto y hay muchos tutoriales en español e inglés, una comunidad bastante grande y la documentación oficial es muy buena y cargada de ejemplos. En el ambito de la investigación, científico y Big Data es muy usado junto a otros como R.

Comment: @pyring la red  StackExchange promueven el aprendizaje de la **comunidad** mediante preguntas y respuestas por lo que no permite ni promueve la comunicación privada entre usuarios.
Puedes hacer todas las preguntas que quieras o si por ejemplo te surge alguna duda sobre esta respuesta puedes ir al [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) e invocarme usando `@FJSevilla` en un mensaje y si estoy por aquí podemos hablar o incluso crear otra sala de chat. Si es una nueva pregunta que pueda beneficiar a la comunidad mejor crear una pregunta nueva.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda en estos primeros pasos en la comunidad. Desde luego, la promoción de la comunicación pública favorece mucho el intercambio, y hace la ciencia más accesible para todo el mundo. Intentaré asimilar un poco más el código que compartes y el tema de "clases", pero seguro que seguiré preguntando (y ayudando a quien pueda). Si consigo comprender bien estos primeros juegos sencillos, podría quizá en el futuro diseñarse una simulación en la que la producción de señales en cada ronda venga dada por una ecuación que tenga en cuenta las diferentes memorias. Por ahí iré. Sl2

Answer (score 0):

Como puedo hacer un juego guerra de los mundo alguno qu e me pueda ayudar... juego consiste en desarrollar dos escenarios, uno para la entidad invasora y otro 
para la defensa terrestre de manera que:
1. Cada escenario se llenará aleatoriamente con la cantidad y tipos de vehículos o naves 
de cada bando y a su vez, cada vehículo o nave se le genera una cantidad de 
armamento de forma aleatoria.
2. Los disparos se realizarán por turno, un turno por cada bando
3. Cada vez que se acierta, se debe indicar que tipo de vehículo fue destruido
 Debe existir la posibilidad de que un bando se retire, antes de terminar la partida, por lo 
que se declarara ganador al otro bando.
5. Solo existen 3 maneras de ganar 
a. Que un bando se retire
b. Que uno de los bandos tenga más del 80% más vehículos o naves con armas, 
que el bando contrario.
c. Que uno de los bandos cuente con mas del 70% de municiones que el bando 
contrario lo que implica que no podrá defenderse.
6. Al finalizar la partida, el sistema debe generar las estadísticas del juego. 
a. Cantidad de naves generadas y derribadas

Comment: Hola Lilly, La pregunta que formulas la estas haciendo en una respuesta. No es el mejor sitio para hacerla ya que estas respondiendo a una pregunta con otra pregunta. SI necesitas formular una pregunta [te recomiendo esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Te recomiendo que publiques tu pregunta desde la opción "Formular una pregunta", ya que si la colocas como respuesta es muy poco probable que alguien te ayude, además que no es la forma correcta, revisa este link: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask